# Armazenar variável dentro de um While

Tags: php, html, array, mysqli, while

estou com uma dúvida simples mas que ta me quebrando a cabeça:
tenho um form onde há vários checkbox, o valor do checkbox é um número de id, gostaria de criar algo que quando o usuário selecionar um determinado número de checks o sistema fazer uma consulta no banco pra cada id que o usuário selecionou.
Por exemplo, o user selecionou 3 checkbox, e eles contem id 1, 2 e 3, com esses parâmetros o sistema busca no banco o nome relacionado á cada id.
id 1 : nome exemplo 1
id 2 : nome exemplo 2
id 3 : nome exemplo 3

tentei com while, for etc...
segue código até o momento que me mostra o id selecionado:

```
$ocs_imp = $_POST['check_imprime'];
$total=count($ocs_imp);


$inicio = 0;
$ultimo = $total-1;
$arranjo = range($inicio, $ultimo);


     foreach ( arranjo as $n => $v ) {
        echo " o id ".$v." é: ".$ocs_imp[$v]."<br>";
                              }
```

o código acima me mostra, o id0 é 1, o id1 é 2, etc...
agora como posso usar isso para fazer uma consulta ao banco com esse id, e trazer a coluna "nome" deste id, fazendo essa consulta proporcional ao número de checks selecionados? obrigado e desculpa se ficou confuso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar algo assim:

```php
$ids = $_POST['check_imprime'];

// só pra garantir que não terão strings injetadas aqui
foreach($ids as $k => $v) {
  $ids[$k] = (int)$v;
}

$ids = implode(',', $ids);

$sql = "SELECT nome FROM tabela WHERE id IN ($ids)";

// assumindo que as constantes já estejam declaradas...
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME); 

$res = $mysqli->query($sql);

while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
   echo 'ID: ' . $row['nome'] . "\n"
}
```

Não testei esse código mas acho que dá pra você entender a ideia.

Comment: Deu certo André, muito obrigado pela força, simples e perfeito, outra dúvida, precisa mesma aquela parte do foreach? pois o valor recebido não é digitado pelo user, mas sim um value do checkbox.

Comment: @DenisL.Murara É bom para garantir que todos os IDs sejam int (o que não for vira 0). Se for remover você vai ter que escapar os ids antes ou (melhor) usar `prepare` http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php#refsect1-mysqli.prepare-examples